# Do constructivists (or intuitionists) reject real numbers, except the computable ones?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, computation, numbers, constructivism

SEP has a bunch of pages on what (various flavors) of intuitionists or constructivists seem to accept [as a model theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#BasSem) or [as a set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/) (they actually seem to diverge on the latter, in the sense of IZF vs. CZF, at least).

I'm curious how that translates to something more concrete though, e.g. with respect to real numbers. What I (also) saw relevant in SEP's [page on math philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/#Cat) is that there is indeed perhaps a problem (of philosophy) on real numbers in particular because:

> A theorem of Tennenbaum states that all first-order models of Peano Arithmetic in which addition and multiplication are computable functions, are isomorphic to each other. Now our operations of addition and multiplication are computable: otherwise we could never have learned these operations. This, then, is another way in which we may be able to isolate the intended models of our principles of arithmetic. Against this account, however, it may be pointed out that it seems that the categoricity of intended models for real analysis, for instance, cannot be ensured in this manner. For computation on models of the principles of real analysis, we do not have a theorem that plays the role of Tennenbaum’s theorem.

There's technically a concept of [computable [real] number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number):

> computable numbers are the real numbers that can be computed to within any desired precision by a finite, terminating algorithm.

... and I see that that Wikipedia page cites the *Constructive Analysis* of Bishop and Bridges (but alas not for any specific passages), so maybe some constructivists/intuinisists have some take on this, e.g. do do (some) constructivists/intuinisists only accept computable (real) numbers?

Comment: See [Brouwer: The continuum](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/#TheCon) and compare with [Recursive Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#RecuConsMath)

Comment: Iirc Brouwer accepted random reals at least as far as arbitrary digits were assigned to them in choice sequences (but don't quote me on this!). Beyond that, I assume that without a procedure for constructing them like we have for π, an intuitionist/constructivist would tend to reject a "completed" infinite-digit real number.

Comment: See [Choice sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_sequence): "Since Brouwer rejects the idea of a completed infinity, in order to use a sequence (which is, in classical mathematics, an infinite object), we must have a formulation of a finite, constructible object that can serve the same purpose as a sequence. Thus, Brouwer formulated the choice sequence, which is given as a construction, rather than an abstract, infinite object." And see the canonical example of a lawless sequence: the series of rolls of a die. It is not computable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: the "lawless" ones are basically given by a [random oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle#Limitations) in more modern terms. I guess Brouwer had the excuse of having done most of that work before the notions of (Turing) computability etc. were known.

Comment: Maybe useful at least the introductory part of Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, [Constructivism in mathematics: An Introduction. Volume 1 (NorthHolland, 1988)](https://books.google.it/books?id=PQ-GxwEACAAJ)

Comment: I would tend to imagine that most constructivists would balk at "undefinable numbers," to the extent that [that's even a meaningful concept](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44129).

Comment: Kreisel and Troelstra further developed the theory of lawless sequences after the modern computability theory was established, and they were well versed in it. There are different flavors of "constructivism". For traditional intuitionists "constructive" is not limited to Turing computable, it is a quasi-Kantian notion of construction by a "creative" subject.

Comment: Let me also clarify the sense of "reject". It is true that intuitionists and constructivists deny ontological status to the more liberal objects of classical mathematics. But fictionalists similarly deny it to *all* of mathematics, yet they can hardly be said to "reject" mathematics. They rather see it as interpreting it less naively. Conversely, since classically provable results are roughly those whose [negative translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation) are provable intuitionistically, intuitionists can be seen as embracing *all* of them, in their special way.

Comment: Very useful: Joan Rand Moschovakis, [INTUITIONISTIC MATHEMATICS AND LOGIC](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~joan/gvfjrmeng.pdf)

Comment: @Conifold: I can't help but think your comments should be put into an answer, to make the contents searchable. Very interesting points.